# getting errors as like on my localhost elasticsearch::Transport::Transport::Errors::NotAcceptable

Tags: ruby, elasticsearch, localhost

> elasticsearch::Transport::Transport::Errors::NotAcceptable: [406] {"error":"Content-Type header [application/x-www-form-urlencoded] is not supported","status":406}

am getting this errs on my localhost so when i run it on live its work  fine but on my localhost it's rising me as like errors so

Sample of code:

```
def council_with_name(name) begin query_hash = {
  : query => {
    : match => {
      : name => name
    }
  },
  : size => 1
}
response = self.__elasticsearch__.search query_hash result = response.records.to_a.first
return result rescue
return nil end
```

Comment: Please, provide more context of what you actually make to get this error

Comment: when i do  response.records.to_a.first then i got  errors as like while on when i deploy this app on live then it'sworking fine . 
Elasticsearch::Transport::Transport::Errors::NotAcceptable: [406] {"error":"Content-Type header [application/x-www-form-urlencoded] is not supported","status":406}
from /home/shahzad/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p648/gems/elasticsearch-transport-1.0.6/lib/elasticsearch/transport/transport/base.rb:132:in `__raise_transport_error'

Comment: What app you talking about? Provide some code sample so we can help you

Comment: def council_with_name(name)
      begin

        query_hash =
            {
                :query =>
                    {
                        :match =>
                            {
                                :name => name
                            }
                    },
                :size => 1
            }
        response = self.__elasticsearch__.search query_hash
        result = response.records.to_a.first

        return result
      rescue
        return nil
      end

Comment: but when i do response.records.to_a.first it's returning me an error that i have mentioned above

Comment: What ES version do you use?

Comment: {
  "name" : "pcname",
  "cluster_name" : "elasticsearch",
  "cluster_uuid" : "4Xtdz6xVRN6ag5VV52kweQ",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "7.6.1",
    "build_flavor" : "default",
    "build_type" : "deb",
    "build_hash" : "aa751e09be0a5072e8570670309b1f12348f023b",
    "build_date" : "2020-02-29T00:15:25.529771Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "8.4.0",
    "minimum_wire_compatibility_version" : "6.8.0",
    "minimum_index_compatibility_version" : "6.0.0-beta1"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}